# Docker on RHEL 6 Cgroup mounting failing

Tags: docker, rhel6

I'm trying to get my head around something that's been working on a Centos+Vagrant, but not on our providers RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)). A **sudo service docker restart** hands this:

```
Stopping docker:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting cgconfig service: Error: cannot mount cpuset to /cgroup/cpuset: Device or resource busy
/sbin/cgconfigparser; error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Cgroup mounting failed
Failed to parse /etc/cgconfig.conf                           [FAILED]

Starting docker:                                              [  OK  ]
```

The service starts okey enough, but images cannot run. A mounting failed error is shown when I try. And the startup-log also gives a warning or two. Regarding the kernelwarning, centos gives the same and has no problems as Epel should resolve this:

```
WARNING: You are running linux kernel version 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64, which might be unstable running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.8.0.
2014/08/07 08:58:29 docker daemon: 1.1.2 d84a070; execdriver: native; graphdriver:
[1233d0af] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
[1233d0af] +job initserver()
[1233d0af.initserver()] Creating server
2014/08/07 08:58:29 Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
[1233d0af] +job init_networkdriver()
[1233d0af] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)
2014/08/07 08:58:29 WARNING: mountpoint not found
```

Anyone had any success overcoming this problem or should I throw in the towel and wait for the provider to update to RHEL 7?

Comment: Maybe this is a more of a Server Fault question?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not putting up the answer here @CamJackson. Have done so now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same issue.

[image]

(1) check cgconfig status

# /etc/init.d/cgconfig status

if it stopped, restart it

# /etc/init.d/cgconfig restart

check cgconfig is running

[image]

(2) check cgconfig is on

# chkconfig --list cgconfig

cgconfig        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off

if cgconfig is off, turn it on

[image]

(3) if still does not work, may be some cgroups modules is missing. In the kernel .config file, make menuconfig, add those modules into kernel and recompile and reboot

after that, it should be OK

[image]

Comment: How do I do (3)? Can you expand on that?

Comment: Very helpful. Thank!

Comment: Changed this to accepted answer as it is more descriptive and has more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up asking the same question at Google Groups and in the end finding a [solution with some help](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/docker-user/_lBT0WYpTPs/_mjmi8S7m4sJ). What worked for me was this:

```
umount cgroup
sudo service cgconfig start
```

The project of making Docker work was put on halt all the same. Later a problem of network connection for the containers. This took to much time to solve and had to give up.

Comment: Yeah I found your thread there as well and tried this solution. Unfortunately it didn't work for me :( I get `umount: cgroup: not found`, followed by `cannot mount cpuset to /cgroup/cpuset: No such file or directory`, and then `error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf` (among other messages). Full logs can be seen [here](https://snap-ci.com/camjackson/writeitdown/branch/master/logs/defaultPipeline/33/dockerise) (right down the bottom). That build is actually on centos, not rhel. Not sure how much difference that makes.

Comment: I thought centos would be easier, but maybe not :)

Comment: Maybe the provider has some limitations? Not too familiar with Snap-ci myself. Is it for continous integration and running tests?

Comment: Yeah, it's a hosted CI service, and I'm beginning to suspect it might be something to do with the platform that's causing problems. I actually work for the company that makes it (albeit out of an office in a different country), so I shouldn't have any trouble getting support help. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Looks nice 4 sure! Maybe spinning up a plain as vanilla CoreOS on a Vagrant and trying to the same there could give some answers also, or in any case see if it works at all. I used CoreOS with Vagrant before trying to deploy to Rhel6 and that worked fine actually. Or just plainly ask them if Docker works of course :)

Comment: @CamJackson , did you solved this ? I'm with the same problem.

Comment: @ton You mean specifically on SnapCI? No I didn't. I was told they don't support docker yet, so for now I'm just using the built in Heroku deployment mechanism. If I really want to build docker images in the future, I'll probably set up a GoCD server in EC2.

Answer (score 1):

So I spent the whole day trying to rig docker to work on my vps. I was running into this same error. Basically what it came down to was the fact that OpenVZ didn't support docker containers up until a couple months ago. Specifically this RHEL update:

https://openvz.org/Download/kernel/rhel6/042stab105.14

Assuming this is your problem, or some variation of it, the burden of solving it is on your host. They will need to follow these steps:

https://openvz.org/Docker_inside_CT

Answer (score 1):

In my case

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.cgconfig start
```

was generating

> Starting cgconfig service: Error: cannot mount cpu,cpuacct,memory to
>   /cgroup/cpu_and_mem: Device or resource busy /usr/sbin/cgconfigparser;
>   error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Cgroup mounting failed Failed to
>   parse  /etc/cgconfig.conf

i had to use:

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.cgconfig restart
```

and it automagicly umouted and mounted groups

> Stopping cgconfig service: Starting cgconfig service:

Answer (score 1):

it seems like the cgconfig service not running,so check it!

```
# /etc/init.d/cgconfig status
# mkdir -p /cgroup/cpuacct /cgroup/memory /cgroup/devices /cgroup/freezer net_cls /cgroup/blkio
# cat /etc/cgconfig.conf |tail|grep "="|awk '{print "mount -t cgroup -o",$1,$1,$NF}'>cgroup_mount.sh
# sh ./cgroup_mount.sh
# /etc/init.d/cgconfig restart
# /etc/init.d/docker restart
```

Answer (score 0):

This situation occurs when the kernel is booted with cgroup_disable=memory and /etc/cgconfig.conf contains memory   = /cgroup/memory;

This causes only /cgroup/cpuset to be mounted instead of the full set.

Solution: either remove cgroup_disable=memory from your kernel boot options or comment out memory = /cgroup/memory; from cgconfig.conf.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to test this any longer, but I would be happy to accept this as an answer if peeps believe it's a better alternative.

Comment: Does this require a reboot? Commenting memory = /cgroup/memory doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `cgconfig` service startup uses `mount` and `umount` which requires an extra privilege bump from docker.

See the `--privileged=true` flag [here](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run) for more info.

I was able to overcome this issue by starting my container with:
`docker run -it --privileged=true my-image`.

Tested in Centos6, Centos6.5.